# PHP - String spanning multiple lines

Tags: php, string

I'm fairly new to php. I have a very long string, and I don't want to have newlines in it. In python, I would accomplish this by doing the following:

```
new_string = ("string extending to edge of screen......................................."
    + "string extending to edge of screen..............................................."
    + "string extending to edge of screen..............................................."
    )
```

Is there anything like this that I can do in PHP?

Comment: a period concatenates strings in php.... `$x = "str"."ing";`

Comment: not to mention variables need a `$` before them, and a `;` at the end

Comment: in php aslo this would work: $string = "some_string [new line] some_string [new_line] some_string" without adding (.) operatore

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this format:

```
$string="some text...some text...some text...some text..."
."some text...some text...some text...some text...some text...";
```

Where you simply use the concat `.` operator across many lines - PHP doesn't mind new lines - as long as each statement ends with a `;`.

Or

```
$string="some text...some text...some text...some text...";
$string.="some text...some text...some text...some text...";
```

Where each statement is ended with a `;` but this time we use a `.=` operator which is the same as typing:

```
$string="some text...some text...some text...some text...";
$string=$string."some text...some text...some text...some text...";
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way? Something like `$string = { }` so we can easily mark a whole block as string?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) operator:

```
$concatened = 'string1' . 'string2';
```

You can spread this across multiple lines and use it together with the assingment operator :

```
$str  = 'string1';
$str .= 'string2';

...
```

An alternative is to use [`join()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php). `join()` allows to concat and array with strings using a delimiter:

```
$str = join('', array(
    'string1',
    'string2'
));
```